# Range of values for enum in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How large number can I use for enum in Objective-C?
Same as NSInteger?

```
typedef enum {
    myEnumA = -1000,
    myEnumB = 1000,
    myEnumC = 2000
} myEnum;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ObjC is based on C, you'll probably find it matches the standard for that language:

From:

- `c90 3.5.2.2 Enumeration specifiers` <sup>(a)</sup>
- `c99 6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers`
- `c11 6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers`

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer
>   constant expression that has a value representable as an int.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: C90 actually says "integral" rather than "integer" but it means the same thing.